# Separate string by multiple separators and return separators and separated strings

Tags: python, string, split

I want to separate strings by separators constist of more than one char saved in the variable `sep_list`.

My aim then is to receive the last separated string `s1` and the last separator which has `s1` on his right hand side.

```
sep_list = ['→E', '¬E', '↓I']

string1 = "peter →E tom ¬E luis ↓I ed"
string2 = "sigrid →E jose l. ¬E jose t."
```

Applied on `string1` the algorithm should return the string `s1`:

```
"↓I, ed"
```

and applied on `string2` the algorithm should return the string `s1`:

```
"¬E, jose t."
```

What is a way to do that with python?

Comment: The "best" way is a matter of opinion. Worry about doing it at all first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do so using regex:

```
import re

sep_list = ['→E', '¬E', '↓I']

string1 = "peter →E tom ¬E luis ↓I ed"
string2 = "sigrid →E jose l. ¬E jose t."

def separate_string(data, seps):
    pattern = "|".join(re.escape(sep) for sep in seps)
    start, end = [m.span() for m in re.finditer(pattern, data)][-1]

    return f"{data[start:end]},{data[end:]}"

print(separate_string(string1, sep_list))  # ↓I, ed
print(separate_string(string2, sep_list))  # ¬E, jose t.
```

---

- We create a regex pattern by separating each keyword with `|`.
- For each match in the string, we use `m.span()` to retrieve the start and end of the match. We only keep the last match.
- `data[start:end]` is the separator, while `data[end:]` is everything after.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the separators may exist in any order (or not at all), you could do this:

```
sep_list = ['→E', '¬E', '↓I']

string1 = "peter →E tom ¬E luis ↓I ed"
string2 = "sigrid →E jose l. ¬E jose t."

def process(s):
    indexes = []
    for sep in sep_list:
        if (index := s.find(sep)) >= 0:
            indexes.append((index, sep))
    if indexes:
        indexes.sort()
        t = indexes[-1]
        return f"{t[1]},{s[t[0]+len(t[1]):]}"

print(process(string1))
print(process(string2))
```

**Output:**

```
↓I, ed
¬E, jose t.
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: This solution does not need the re module!
Update #2: Shorter solution.

```
def run(string):
    sep_lst = ['→E', '¬E', '↓I']
    tokens = string.split()
    result = None
    for i,token in enumerate(tokens):
        if token in sep_lst:
            result = f'{tokens[i]}, {" ".join(tokens[i+1:])}'
    return result

print(run("peter →E tom ¬E luis ↓I ed"))
print(run("sigrid →E jose l. ¬E jose t."))
```

Output:

```
↓I, ed
¬E, jose t.
```